# Form Class Not Working

Tags: html, css, forms, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the style of my bootstrap form to my own custom css. So, I create a class in my form, but the changes I make to the class's css isn't changing the style of the form.

Here's my form:

```
<li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                  <form  class="login-form" action="[YOUR ACTION]" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                  <input id="user_username" placeholder="Email" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user_username" size="30" />
                  <input id="user_password" placeholder="Password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="user_password" size="30" />
                  <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user_remember_me" value="1" />
                  <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>
                  <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
                  </form>
                  </div>
                </li>
```

And here's my css:

```
    .login-form {
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:60px;
}
```

Comment: There's a good chance that your changes are being overwritten by an external stylesheet.  Try adding `!important` to the end of some of your new css rules.

Comment: How do you load your css? Inline in the html or as an external file? It would be much easier to pinpoint the problem if you provide a full example.

Comment: An external css file.

Comment: @AnthonyHilyard: You’re right with the first part; the second one however should rather be, “use a more specific selector (or at least one of the same specificity, if your stylesheet is embedded after the bootstrap one)”.

Comment: !important actually works. However, isn't that really bad "style" and frowned upon?

Answer (score 0):

If .login-form class is coming from an external style sheet you should determine that the style sheet is being loaded by the browsers. In Chrome go to the View menu and from the Developer submenu choose Developer Tools. For most these tools appear at the bottom of the browsers' view port. Click on the Sources tab and then click on your CSS file; if you see the CSS then the style is loading. If not, then the style is not loading and it may be a problem with the URL that points to the style sheet.

Additionally you should validate your style sheet in W3C validator as an error in an earlier or later style could be causing a cascading error. Common Cascading errors are failing to properly close a style rule with a curly brace or terminating a property's value(s) with a semi-colon.

Comment: I just checked, my css file is being loaded by the browser.

Comment: Does the CSS validate?